# Drupal EntityForm hooks

Tags: drupal-modules

I am using drupal Entity-Form module, I have successfully achieved the user interface part of it. But when i am trying to hook the Entity-form submission, I am not able to get any thing..

I have tried `hook_form_alter()`, `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`, but nothing.
Has any one achieved it...? I have tried all below:-

```
function form_submit_igs_entity_views_field_handlers_alter(array &$field_handlers){
    echo "pankaj";
}

function _form_entityform_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    echo "pankaj";
}

function form_submit_igs_entity_presave($entity, $type){
    echo "pankaj";
}

function form_submit_igs_node_view_alter(&$build){
    echo "pankaj";
}
function form_submit_igs_field_attach_submit($entity_type, $entity, $form, &$form_state){
    echo "pankaj";
}

function form_submit_igs_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    echo "pankaj";  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I figured it out:
I wrote a hook_form_alter() function it looked like this
`function hook_form_alter()(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    dpm($form);
}`
from that I could get a formID on the existing form & then get the appropriate name for the function.

Note you can also do:

`function hook_form_entityform_edit_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    dpm($form);
}`
To alter only entity forms.

in both instances `hook` is to be replaced by your module name. Install devel module to get `dpm()` function to work and not throw an error.

Hope this helps you figure out your issue.

Comment: OOOHHHH, you're using the EntityForm module, not just any entity.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to archive, your description is not very good, but anyway.
To alter any entityform form you need to use, as by [entityform_forms()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_forms/7), **$machine_name . '_entityform_edit_form'** as form ID, so your function will look like this **some_func_form_YOUR_ENTITY_FORM_NAME_entityform_edit_form_alter()**.

Answer (score 0):

I have used hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(), you must use your particular entityform's machine name plus *_entityform* after the machine name. For example if your entityform's machine name is "myentityform" and your module name is "mymodule", the hook_form_FORM_ID_alter will be:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_myentityform_entityform_edit_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  // Your codes
}
```